# Show student's result when they enter roll number in Google Form

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Sheet with all students subject marks, roll numbers, names.

I'm thinking of following:
Students are given URL of a Google Form. Only field there is for roll number. Once they entry their roll number, & click 'Next', they are shown their respective marks against each subject in the next section.
Please advise if this is achievable? Or how else to do it?

I'm not a software programmer as such, but do poke around stuff.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve...? And also this is considerably insecure. Why not just email the student result directly to their respective student email (the official student email)

Comment: We do send out emails through mail merge etc, but there are certain restrictions in that. 
Therefore, what we are looking for is an app/system, which can retrieve the student's marks of a particular semester/test, and show it to them once they enter their roll number. Because these are stored on Google Sheet, I thought maybe there will be a way to acheive this functionality through Google Forms.

Answer (score 0):

Google Forms is intened to create forms to collect data, not to create views of data, in other words, it's not a tool to create web applications.

As you already have the data in a spreadsheet you might use it or a another having a cell where the students enter they roll number the using FILTER, QUERY, VLOOKUP, INDEX and MATCH and maybe other functions show to the corresponding marks.

If you are looking for a no code tool to create a web app, try AppSheet which is included in some editions of Google Workspace (formerly G Suite) and it's a shown in the Google Sheets tools menu for users of these editions.